# Question about normal subgroup and isomorphism relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Maybe by using the following theorem:

> If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the function $\phi: G \to G/N,$ given by $\phi(g)=gN$ yields a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $G/N$ with $\ker(\phi)=N$.

I want to solve the following exercise:

$G=$ the group of all matrices of the form $ \pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & b }$ where $b \neq 0$.

$N$ is the group of all matrices of the form $\pmatrix{1 & c \\ 0 & 1 }$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$. It's a normal subgroup of $G$, because $gng^{-1} \in N$ for all $g\in G,n\in N$.

Now I have to show that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0 \}$ and $G/N$ are isomorphic. I should do this by showing that $\phi(b) \mapsto \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b } N$ is an isomorphism So we have a $b\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0 \}$ is an isomorphism...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: remember the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem): you could define

$$\phi:G\to\Bbb R-\{0\}:=\Bbb R^*\;,\;\;\phi\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\0&b\end{pmatrix}:=b$$

Prove the above is a group homomorphism between $\,G\,$ and $\,\Bbb R^*\,$ whose kernel is $\,N\,$ and now apply the FIT...

Comment: tnx. The chapter did not write about the isomorphism theorems, so I guess there is another method to solve this.

Comment: What chapter of **what** book, please?

Comment: just a chapter from a reader, no official book.

Comment: I should do this by showing that $\phi(b) \mapsto \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b } N$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @MSKfdaswplwq: DonAntonio's method is a much better way. If you want to show $X$ and $Y/Z$ are isomorphic, it is almost always best to define a function from $Y$ to $X$ with kernel $Z$. The main reason to do it the “wrong” way ($X$ to $Y/Z$) is to see how awkward the wrong way is.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not allowed to use the isomorphism theorems, note that you have a unique decomposition
$$\tag{dec}
\pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & b }
=
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b }
\pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & 1 },
$$
with 
$$
\pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & 1 } \in N, \qquad \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b } \in H,
$$
where
$$
H = \left\{ \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b } : b \in \Bbb{R}^{\star} \right\}
$$
is a subgroup visibly isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{\star}$. Now (dec) implies that each coset
$$
\pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & b } N
$$
of $N$ can be written uniquely as
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b } N,
$$
hence the required isomorphism.

Comment: thanks. But I should do this by showing that $\phi(b) \mapsto \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b } N$ is an isomorphism. How can I relate your work with that?

Comment: @MSKfdaswplwq: You have two neat approaches. You,now, should be able to defeat the problem.

Comment: @MSKfdaswplwq, the coset representatives $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & b }$ form a subgroup $H$, which intersects the normal subgroup $N$ trivially. (The group is a so-called *semidirect product*.) Hence multiplication in $G/N$ is the same as in $H$.